# model is extremely small when importing into Unreal 5

Tags: mesh, armature, export, .fbx, unreal-engine

I'm pretty new to modeling and am having some trouble getting my model to be the correct size after import to Unreal 5. everything I have read/watched tells me to make my scene unit scale .01. This does give m the proper anatomical height of a human. However, when I import the meta rigged model into Unreal 5, the model is way smaller than the starter SK_manny model. I have to make my scene unit scale 1 with an item scale of .13. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have been at this for hours now...

Here is a link to my blender file [Goldy.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11cxdlkSdnDVOsKl-gHyqXQN3QdXj1SSn/view?usp=sharing)

thanks for the help!

Comment: I've never adjusted the unit scale when I exported fbx from Blender to Unreal and it worked fine.

Comment: maybe ill just go that route then everyone makes scaling seem extremely important. but i guess if it works scale wise reguardless of the scale units it really does not matter